# Доступ к SolidColorBrush(прописан в разм.) из кода. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderThickness="2" Opacity="1">

    <Border.Background x:Name="CardBoxesBackground">
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" Opacity="0.5" x:Name="CardBoxesSolidColorBrush"/>
    </Border.Background>

</Border>
```

Хочу получить доступ  из кода

```
 SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();

 далее несколько вариантов

 brush.Color = MainBorder.Background.SolidColorBrush;
```

или

```
brush.Color = MainBorder.Background.CardBoxesSolidColorBrush;
```

Ни один вариант не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderThickness="2" Opacity="1">
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" Opacity="0.5"/>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

и в code-behind:

```
var brush = (SolidColorBrush)MainBorder.Background;
brush.Color = Colors.Red;
```

или даже так:

```
MainBorder.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

или там

```
MainBorder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) { Opacity = 0.5 };
```